# Getting Integers from Char Array?

Tags: java, arrays, char, int

I was experimenting with `char` arrays and integers, when I found something that confused me a lot. In Java, if you type the following code:

```
String inputs = "123";
char[] inputs2 = inputs.toCharArray(); // Turn String into Char Array
int a = inputs2[0];

println(a);
```

I would have expected for "a" to return 1 because 1 is the first element in the array. However, it returned 49. Why does this occur? Is there any way to get around this issue?